# changing custom domain from one project to another project

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have two projects, A, and B. Both are using Firebase hosting and both are live. I would like to remove the custom domain from project A and use it for project B. I have already deleted the custom domain from project A. I have also added it to project B. However, the custom domain is still serving up project A.

When I added the custom domain to project B (after removing it from project A), the Firebase hosting wizard didn't prompt me with any TXT records like it had originally when I hooked up the custom domain for project An (or any other projects I have hosted using Firebase). The wizard jumped right to the prompt instructing me to add the two different A records to my DNS setup.
I added those two to my DNS, but the TXT record is the same as it was for project An (I just left it in place because I wasn't provided with another).
How do I get that custom domain to serve up the correct Firebase project? Any ideas would be helpful. Should I remove the TXT record in order for it to prompt me with another one?

Answer (score 0):

If Project B is showing the domain as connected but is still showing Project A when visited, that sounds like a bug or caching issue. I'd recommend:

1. Redeploy your site to Project B.
2. Hard refresh in the browser.
3. If that fails, try `curl -X PURGE https://your.domain.com/`

If all of that doesn't show the correct site, check very closely that you've typed everything correctly in both projects and [contact Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact).

Comment: I gave all of those options a try. Still hasn't produced the results I want. I submitted to Firebase support so I will hopefully be able to update this with a solution next week sometime.

Comment: Try pushing some changes... maybe it could overwrite the previous config

Comment: @MarkRosenberg A bit late to this, but did you manage to figure it out?